# ComboBox data extraction?

Tags: c#, datagridview, combobox

my method is:

```
  {
            conn.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand
            ("select BusinessEntityID from Person.Person order by'BusinessEntityID' ASC", conn);
            SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                comboBox1.Items.Add(dr["BusinessEntityID"]);
            }
            conn.Close();
        }
```

but that's not what I want. I have a class. update, insert, and delete list that also includes methods. a draw method of the ComboBox here I write data in the form side of the DataSource of the ComboBox I can I take it?  In my system, every time the form on the side, I am forced to open and close connections.

for example, I take like DataGridView data

class side

```
       public DataTable list()
    {
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter
            ("select * from HumanResources.Employee", OpenConnection());
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(dt);
        CloseConnection();
        return dt;
    }
```

form side

```
            dataGridView1.DataSource = data.list();
```

Comment: ComboBox also has a DataSource.  Just set the DisplayMember and ValueMember properties if need be.

Comment: Could you please give an example? I'm new to c #

Comment: `comboBox1.DataSource = data.list();`  You should start by getting a tutorial book.  Plenty at Amazon.

Comment: i can not:( please help me :( 

form side : 

        {
            conn.Open();
           SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand
            ("select BusinessEntityID from Person.Person order by'BusinessEntityID' ASC", conn);
            SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                comboBox1.Items.Add(dr["BusinessEntityID"]);
            }
            conn.Close();
        }

this, I should write at class. and I need to call on the side of the form

Comment: @onur_t I don't understand exactly what is what you want to accomplish.  Can you please rephrase your question?